# Trubble sending emil with cc and bcc using php

Tags: php, html

i have a html form with a php email script .. but when try to send an email it shows an error .. 
Recipient is blank! .

```
<?php

$message= " " ;
if (empty ( $mailtoname) || empty ( $mailtomail) ) {
die ( "Recipient is blank! ") ;
}else{
$to = $mailtoname . " <" . $mailtomail . ">" ;
}

if ( empty ( $mailsubject) ) {
$mailsubject=" ";
}

if (($mailpriority>0) && ($mailpriority<6)) {
$mailheader = "X-Priority: ". $mailpriority ."\n";
}

$mailheader.= "From: " . "Sales Team <sales@yourdomain.com>\n";
$mailheader.= "X-Sender: " . "support@yourdomain.com\n";
$mailheader.= "Return-Path: " . "support@yourdomain.com\n";

if (!empty($mailcc)) {
$mailheader.= "Cc: " . $mailcc ."\n";
}

if (!empty($mailbcc)) {
$mailheader.= "Bcc: " . $mailbcc ."\n";
}

if (empty($mailbody)) {
$mailbody=" ";
}

$result = mail ($to, $mailsubject, $mailbody, $mailheader);
echo "<center><b>Mail sent to ". "$to". "<br>";
echo $mailsubject. "<br>";
echo $mailbody. "<br>";
echo $mailheader. "<br>";
if ($result) {
echo "<p><b>Email sent successfully!</b></p>";
}else{
echo "<p><b>Email could not be sent. </b></p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Giving your code a quick glance, you are not calling your `$_POST` data correctly in the PHP page that processes the form data.

Example, in your PHP page you are using `$mailheader.= "Cc: " . $mailcc ."\n";`  You need to call the data that was sent via POST:  `$mailheader.= "Cc: " . $_POST['mailcc'] ."\n";`

I see other things that may or may not cause errors...fix all of those in your PHP processing page and if it still doesn't work then I can go further.

Comment: http://www.pstwist.com/send-cc-email/ here you find the form and php script .. can you please edit it and send .. I will be so thank full to you

Comment: waiting for your precious answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$message= " " ;
if (empty ( $_POST['mailtoname']) || empty ( $_POST['mailtomail']) ) {
die ( "Recipient is blank! ") ;
}else{
$to = $_POST['mailtoname'] . " <" . $_POST['mailtomail'] . ">" ;
}

if ( empty ( $_POST['mailsubject']) ) {
    $mailsubject=" ";
}

else {
    $mailsubject = $_POST['mailsubject'];
}

if (($_POST['mailpriority']>0) && ($_POST['mailpriority']<6)) {
$mailheader = "X-Priority: ". $_POST['mailpriority'] ."\n";
}

$mailheader.= "From: " . "Sales Team <sales@yourdomain.com>\n";
$mailheader.= "X-Sender: " . "support@yourdomain.com\n";
$mailheader.= "Return-Path: " . "support@yourdomain.com\n";

if (!empty($_POST['mailcc'])) {
$mailheader.= "Cc: " . $_POST['mailcc'] ."\n";
}

if (!empty($_POST['mailbcc'])) {
$mailheader.= "Bcc: " . $_POST['mailbcc'] ."\n";
}

if (empty($_POST['mailbody'])) {
$mailbody=" ";
}

else {
    $mailbody = $_POST['mailbody'];
}

$result = mail ($to, $mailsubject, $mailbody, $mailheader);
echo "<center><b>Mail sent to ". "$to". "<br>";
echo $mailsubject. "<br>";
echo $mailbody. "<br>";
echo $mailheader. "<br>";
if ($result) {
echo "<p><b>Email sent successfully!</b></p>";
}else{
echo "<p><b>Email could not be sent. </b></p>";
}
?>
```

No clue if that will work because edits have deleted the link to your HTML form, but give that a run (just replacing all of your form variables with `$_POST['variable']` .  Even if this WORKS, you should read up on sanitizing your form inputs.